# How to vectorize a code with python numpy.bincount, using apply along axis

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize a code with numpy, to run it using multiprocessing, but i can't understand how `numpy.apply_along_axis` works. This is an example of the code, vectorized using `map`

```
import numpy
from scipy import sparse
import multiprocessing
from matplotlib import pyplot

#first i build a matrix of some x positions vs time datas in a sparse format
matrix = numpy.random.randint(2, size = 100).astype(float).reshape(10,10)
x = numpy.nonzero(matrix)[0]
times = numpy.nonzero(matrix)[1]
weights = numpy.random.rand(x.size)

#then i define an array of y positions
nStepsY = 5
y = numpy.arange(1,nStepsY+1)

#now i build an image using x-y-times coordinates and x-times weights
def mapIt(ithStep):
    ncolumns = 80
    image = numpy.zeros(ncolumns)

    yTimed = y[ithStep]*times
    positions = (numpy.round(x-yTimed)+50).astype(int)

    values = numpy.bincount(positions,weights)
    values = values[numpy.nonzero(values)]
    positions = numpy.unique(positions)
    image[positions] = values
    return image


image = list(map(mapIt, range(nStepsY)))
image = numpy.array(image)

a = pyplot.imshow(image, aspect = 10)
```

[Here the output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XnSv.png)

I tried to use `numpy.apply_along_axis`, but this function allows me to iterate only along the rows of `image`, while i need to iterate along the ithStep index too. E.g.:

```
#now i build an image using x-y-times coordinates and x-times weights
nrows = nStepsY
ncolumns = 80
matrix = numpy.zeros(nrows*ncolumns).reshape(nrows,ncolumns)

def applyIt(image):

    image = numpy.zeros(ncolumns)

    yTimed = y[ithStep]*times
    positions = (numpy.round(x-yTimed)+50).astype(int)

    values = numpy.bincount(positions,weights)
    values = values[numpy.nonzero(values)]
    positions = numpy.unique(positions)
    image[positions] = values

    return image


imageApplied = numpy.apply_along_axis(applyIt,1,matrix)
a = pyplot.imshow(imageApplied, aspect = 10)
```

It obviously return only the firs row `nrows` times, since nothing iterates `ithStep`:
[And here the wrong plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVzg7.png)

There is a way to iterate an index, or to use an index while `numpy.apply_along_axis` iterates?

---

Here the code with only matricial operations: it's quite faster than `map` or `apply_along_axis` but uses so much memory.

(in this function i use a trick with `scipy.sparse`, which works more intuitively than numpy arrays when you try to sum numbers on a same element)

```
def fullmatrix(nRows, nColumns):
    y = numpy.arange(1,nStepsY+1)
    image = numpy.zeros((nRows, nColumns))

    yTimed = numpy.outer(y,times)
    x3d = numpy.outer(numpy.ones(nStepsY),x)
    weights3d = numpy.outer(numpy.ones(nStepsY),weights)
    y3d = numpy.outer(y,numpy.ones(x.size))
    positions = (numpy.round(x3d-yTimed)+50).astype(int)

    matrix = sparse.coo_matrix((numpy.ravel(weights3d), (numpy.ravel(y3d), numpy.ravel(positions)))).todense()
    return matrix

image = fullmatrix(nStepsY, 80)
a = pyplot.imshow(image, aspect = 10)
```

---

This way is simplier and very fast! Thank you so much.

```
nStepsY = 5
nRows = nStepsY
nColumns = 80
y = numpy.arange(1,nStepsY+1)
image = numpy.zeros((nRows, nColumns))
fakeRow = numpy.zeros(positions.size)

def itermatrix(ithStep):
    yTimed = y[ithStep]*times
    positions = (numpy.round(x-yTimed)+50).astype(int)

    matrix = sparse.coo_matrix((weights, (fakeRow, positions))).todense()
    matrix = numpy.ravel(matrix)
    missColumns = (nColumns-matrix.size)
    zeros = numpy.zeros(missColumns)
    matrix = numpy.concatenate((matrix, zeros))
    return matrix

for i in numpy.arange(nStepsY):
    image[i] = itermatrix(i)

#or, without initialization of image:
imageMapped = list(map(itermatrix, range(nStepsY)))
imageMapped = numpy.array(imageMapped)
```

Comment: I haven't looked into the details of what you have done, but my gut-feeling is that this might be a good fit for numpy.vectorize. Have you looked at that?

Comment: @JohanL np.vectorize doesn't actually vectorize a function. It is basically a loop under the hood.

Comment: So is `apply_along_axis`.  It iterates on all dimensions except the chosen one, passing a 1d array to your function.  So in a 3d case it is easier to use than nested loops, but not faster.  If it is hard to apply to your case, don't bother.

Comment: `np.vectorize` passes scalars to your function.  It's handy if your matrix can have several dimensions, or you need to broadcast several inputs, but it too is not a speed alternative to your own iteration.

Comment: There isn't any wrapper that will run your `mapIt` function faster.  You'd have to rework the function itself, but with functions like `bincount` and `unique` that will be difficult.  As long as `nStepsY` is relatively small, the iteration is not costing much in performance.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you. At the moment i'm not looking for better performances, but only in a way to vectorize this code using only numpy functions. In my work with this code i'm writing, i have to manage very big arrays. So, for example, it's not much feasible to populate every `nStepsY` rows of `positions` and then populate `image`

Comment: (where for 'populate every `nStepsY` rows of `positions`' i mean obviously with outer products and matricial operations, since `positions` depends on `ithStep` and as far as i understand, it is impossible to use `apply_along_axis` like `map`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like attempting to use `map` or `apply_along_axis` is obscuring the essentially iteration of the problem.

I rewrote your code as an explicit loop on `y`:

```
nStepsY = 5
y = numpy.arange(1,nStepsY+1)
image = numpy.zeros((nStepsY, 80))
for i, yi in enumerate(y):
    yTimed = yi*times
    positions = (numpy.round(x-yTimed)+50).astype(int)
    values = numpy.bincount(positions,weights)
    values = values[numpy.nonzero(values)]
    positions = numpy.unique(positions)
    image[i, positions] = values
a = pyplot.imshow(image, aspect = 10)
pyplot.show()
```

Looking at the code, I think I could calculate `positions` for all `y` values making a `(y.shape[0],times.shape[0])` array.  But the rest, the `bincount` and `unique` still have to work `row by row`.

`apply_along_axis` when working with a 2d array, and axis=1 essentially does:

```
res = np.zeros_like(arr)
for i in range....:
   res[i,:] = func1d(arr[i,:])
```

If the input array has more dimensions it constructs a more elaborate indexing object `[i,j,k,:]`.  And it can handle cases where `func1d` returns a different size array than the input.  But in any case it is just a generalized iteration tool.

---

Moving the initial `positions` creation outside the loop:

```
yTimed = y[:,None]*times
positions = (numpy.round(x-yTimed)+50).astype(int)
image = numpy.zeros((positions.shape[0], 80))
for i, pos in enumerate(positions):
    values = numpy.bincount(pos,weights)
    values = values[numpy.nonzero(values)]
    pos = numpy.unique(pos)
    image[i, pos] = values
```

Now I can cast this as an `apply_along_axis` problem, with an `applyIt` that takes a `positions` vector (with all the `yTimed` information) rather than blank `image` vector.

```
def applyIt(pos, size, weights):
    acolumn = numpy.zeros(size)
    values = numpy.bincount(pos,weights)
    values = values[numpy.nonzero(values)]
    pos = numpy.unique(pos)
    acolumn[pos] = values
    return acolumn

image = numpy.apply_along_axis(applyIt, 1, positions, 80, weights)
```

Timing wise I expect it's a bit slower than my explicit iteration.  It has to do more setup work, including a test call `applyIt(positions[0,:],...)` to determine the size of its return array (i.e `image` has different shape than `positions`.)

---

```
def csrmatrix(y, times, x, weights):
    yTimed = numpy.outer(y,times)
    n=y.shape[0]
    x3d = numpy.outer(numpy.ones(n),x)
    weights3d = numpy.outer(numpy.ones(n),weights)
    y3d = numpy.outer(y,numpy.ones(x.size))
    positions = (numpy.round(x3d-yTimed)+50).astype(int)
    #print(y.shape, weights3d.shape, y3d.shape, positions.shape)
    matrix = sparse.csr_matrix((numpy.ravel(weights3d), (numpy.ravel(y3d), numpy.ravel(positions))))
    #print(repr(matrix))
    return matrix
# one call
image = csrmatrix(y, times, x, weights)
# iterative call
alist = []
for yi in numpy.arange(1,nStepsY+1):
    alist.append(csrmatrix(numpy.array([yi]), times, x, weights))

def mystack(alist):
    # concatenate without offset
    row, col, data = [],[],[]
    for A in alist:
        A = A.tocoo()
        row.extend(A.row)
        col.extend(A.col)
        data.extend(A.data)
    print(len(row),len(col),len(data))
    return sparse.csr_matrix((data, (row, col)))

vimage = mystack(alist)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My main problems are: my three initial arrays `x`,`times`,`weights` are really huge (order of 10^6 elements each one); my final goal is to parallelize the code. For the first reason i can't use matricial operations, for the second i'd like to vectorize in numpy. I tried to use only matrices but my pc go out of memory :(

Comment: I edited my question adding the function i'd use if i had infinite RAM (or tiny arrays), just to give an example.

Comment: Be careful about terminology.  What I did to move the `positions` calculation out of the loop is an example numpy `vectorization`.  I applied fast array operations like `*` and `round` to a 2d array, rather than row by row.  But functions like `bincount` and `unique` work with 1d arrays, so can't be extended to apply to all `y` times at once.  Hiding a loop in a function like `apply_along_axis` is not numpy vectorization.   The goal of numpy 'vectorization' is to use 'matrical operations'.  If the problem is too big for that, stick with iteration.

Comment: I was going to say that an explicit iteration of `y` is better than `map` because it's clearer.  But the `map` approach may be easier to cast as a multiprocessing problem, with map pools and such.

Comment: The `sparse.coo` approach is interesting.   But I don't see, off hand, why that would have a greater memory problem than your iterative bincount approach.  But maybe that belongs in a separate question.

Comment: Becouse a sparse matrix is basically a 3-columns array (row coordinates, column coordinates, values). I chose to define it with `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` using 3 arrays that must broadcast together correctly. Since `yTimed` and `positions` are 2D arrays with shape `x.size, y.size`, the problem is that i have to expand every other array from 1D to 2D, basically copying them `nStepsY` times. Well, when `x.size` is ~10^6 and  `nStepsY=y.size` is ~10^2 this is definitely a problem.

Comment: In other words you have to give the sparse matrix all the points before the 'binning'.  It bins on conversion to `csr` or `dense`.  I've worked out how to feed the sparse function your `y` values iteratively, and do a 'stack' of the binned results.  But I don't know if that extra work is worth it.

Comment: If you mean the `sparse.hstack` function i tried memory problems blocked me at the moment. I'm opening a new question, so we can discuss there

Comment: I had to write my own join, but haven't tested on anything big.

Comment: Nevermind! Thanks to you i retried and i solved it! Now i have doubled speed with no memory problems :D I'm editing my question to show you the code